# How can we define a type of symmetric binary operations in Agda?

Tags: types, agda

I don't understand how we can define in Agda a type of "Symmetric Binary Relation". Imagine I have something like:

```hs
{-
  First, we define a polymorphic idenity
-}
data _==_ {A : Set} (a : A) : A → Set where
  definition-of-idenity : a == a
infix 30 _==_

{-
 Next we define the finite set Ω = {A,B,C}
-}
data Ω : Set where
  A B C : Ω

{-
 We add a type "Binary operation"
-}
BinaryOperation = Ω → Ω → Ω

{-
 I can actually define an example of Binary operation.
-}
_⊙_ : BinaryOperation
x ⊙ x' = A
infix 40 _⊙_

{-
 And then I can proove that ⊙ is Symmetric
-}
proof-of-symmetry : ∀ x y → x ⊙ y == y ⊙ x
proof-of-symmetry = λ x y → definition-of-idenity
```

How we can define a type "Symmetric Binary Operation"?
Having this type we will be able to define ⊙ as

```hs
_⊙_ : SymmetricBinaryOperation
x ⊙ y = A
```

and proof that ⊙ is symmetric will no be required.

Comment: You can't just say, that `_⊙_` is symmetric without actually providing a proof of this fact. Hence there is no way to define `_⊙_` as `_⊙_ : SymmetricBinaryOperation; x ⊙ y = A`, unless you use type classes. The usual way to define relations is to pack operations among with proofs in records. You can found examples in the standard library [here](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~nad/repos/lib/src/Relation/Binary.agda). Check also [this](http://people.inf.elte.hu/divip/AgdaTutorial/Sets.Records.html) tutorial. And [this](http://cs.ioc.ee/~james/papers/AssistedMonads2.pdf) paper is instructive.

Comment: @user3237465 so, records are better than data-s ?

Comment: In most cases. The difference is much like between Haskell's `newtype`s and `data`s. Agda also has eta-laws for records and performs sophisticated [pattern unification](http://www2.tcs.ifi.lmu.de/~abel/talkTLCA11.pdf). Rarely you don't want to have eta, as stated [here](http://agda.chalmers.narkive.com/l79pECtC/dummie-question-why-records#post4), but the example at the link is deprecated now, and I'm not aware of another.

Comment: My question is also related to so called "subtyping" that is not possible in Agda (if I uderstood correctly). For example, [here](http://mazzo.li/posts/AgdaSort.html) Francesco uses the type Olist that means "Ordered List" but he also use an annoying coertion funtion "toList : ∀ {l u} → OList l u → List X" that converts from Olist to List. It works but look very ulgy for me.

Comment: Agda has some subtyping via instance arguments (check e.g. [this](https://github.com/effectfully/random-stuff/blob/master/stuff/liftA.agda): in the `liftA` function an `Applicative` is in the scope, while `_<$>_` requires a `Functor`). But you probably mean [coercive subtyping](http://elanguage.net/journals/index.php/salt/article/view/20.38), which is indeed not presented in Agda.

Comment: There is also a thread in the Agda's mailing list https://lists.chalmers.se/pipermail/agda/2015/thread.html#7741

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating my comment: there would be no way to define `SymmetricBinaryOperation` as you want, even if there were a decision procedure for checking symmetryness, because `SymmetricBinaryOperation` must carry a `Symmetry` proof about the operation being defined. I.e. the operation must mention itself in its own type signature, which is clearly a loop. (Hence my point about type classes is senseless too).

Comment: Thanks. Also I found @cody 's [answer](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/16975) to a question of mrsteve. Cody talks about "refinement types [that] capture the notion of contracts, and are also related to axiomatic semantics or Hoare logic". It's exaclty what I'm spekaing about.

Comment: @Sergey Kirgizov, the proofs-in-a-meta-language approach leads to the dark side of the Force.